# Como puedo agregar formato en el encabezado a archivo de excel desde C# via COM/Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms

Me gustaria saber como puedo darle formato al encabezado de mi archivo de excel que genero para exportar, estoy usando COM/interop excel 16.0, les muestro mi codigo con el que recorre mi datagridview y despues pasa a excel:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

        object[,] datos = new object[tabla.Rows.Count + 1, tabla.Columns.Count]; // +1 por la cabecera
        for (int j = 0; j < tabla.Columns.Count; j++) //cabeceras
        {
            datos[0, j] = tabla.Columns[j].Name;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tabla.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                datos[i + 1, j] = tabla.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear un estilo y asignarlo a un rango

Ejemplo

```
private Style GetStyleHeader(Workbook wb)
{
    Style style = wb.Styles.Add("MiEstilo");
    style.Font.Bold = true;
    style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    style.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
          
    return style;
}
```

Código completo:

```
private object[,] GetDataFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    object[,] datos = new object[dataGridView1.Rows.Count + 1, dataGridView1.Columns.Count]; // +1 por la cabecera
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        datos[0, j] = dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            datos[i + 1, j] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;
        }
        progressBar1.Value++;
    }
    return datos;
}
private Style GetStyleHeader(Workbook wb)
{
    Style style = wb.Styles.Add("MiEstilo");
    style.Font.Bold = true;
    style.HorizontalAlignment = XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    style.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    style.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
          
    return style;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
    var datos = GetDataFromDGV(dataGridView1);
    var style = GetStyleHeader(excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook);

    excel.Range[excel.Cells[1, 1], excel.Cells[1, datos.GetLength(1)]].Style = style;
    excel.Range[excel.Cells[1, 1], excel.Cells[datos.GetLength(0), datos.GetLength(1)]].Value = datos;
    excel.Visible = true;
    Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
    worksheet.Activate();
}
```

Fuente: [Documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-apply-styles-to-ranges-in-workbooks?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Excelente, te agradezco una vez más por tu ayuda... una pregunta más sabrias como hacer para que cuando se exporte las columnas y filas tomen todo el espacio de las celdas? no se si me explique bien

Comment: @RicardoPalacios Me alegro te haya servido. Te refieres a que la cela de expanda para que el contenido no se vea cortado?? o es otra cosa?

Comment: Si, asi es... tengo entendido que es al rango y aplicar autifill verdad? pero solo es para columnas y quisiera que sea para filas y columnas

Comment: @RicardoPalacios La verdad es que para las filas no se hacerlo ni a mano en el mismo Excel

Comment: Bueno igualmente te agradezco tu ayuda :)